# Passing route parameter to the Controller Action method

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, route-provider

I have some routes that invokes mvc controller actions, and i want to pass values to action parameter:

route Hyperlink in view is:

```
<a href="#viewMeeting">{{obj.Meetingsubject}}</a>
```

My route code is:

```
$routeProvider.when("/viewMeeting", {
        templateUrl: "/Meetings/ViewMeeting"
    });
```

MVC Controller actions code is:

```
public ActionResult ViewMeeting(int MeetingId)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

The above code is working fine. but i want to pass "MeetingId" to controller action. Which method i can use to pass parameter from routeProvider?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like :

In HTML(use `ng-href`):

```
<a ng-href="#viewMeeting/{{obj.MeetingId}}">{{obj.Meetingsubject}}</a>
```

In Route config :

```
$routeProvider.when("/viewMeeting/:meetingId", {
        templateUrl: "/Meetings/ViewMeeting?MeetingId=" + params.meetingId
    });
```